# Javascript scroll offset

Tags: javascript, scroll, offset

I want to get page offset every time I scroll. I tried `console.log(window.pageYOffset)`. But I need something like a button to console it. How can it console page offset every time I scroll?

Comment: You can add the code to `window.addEventListener('scroll', function() { //your code goes here })`

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. You know how to get the scroll offset, you just have to repeat it every time you scroll.

Fortunately, we have an event called `scroll`, that does exactly what you expect from its name.

Add a listener to it, that logs `pageYOffset`:

```js
 window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  console.log(window.pageYOffset)
})
```

```html
<div style="height: 5000px; background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, white, red)">Some content to scroll</div>
```